# How to disable Done in soft keyboard

Tags: android

In nexus 5, the soft keyboard provides emoticons in edittext view, there is a "Done" button next to the dot "." button, if I long click on the "Done" button it will present two choices, one with this "Prev" and one with "Smiley face" that will open the emoticons.

Since the emoticons is already there in the default keyboard there is no need to write one, so, is it possible to remove the "Done" in XML or Java? if yes, will the "smiley face" button be there after removing the "Done" button?

Comment: dont disable Done and Next from the keyboard they are there for a reason. Consider you have 3 edittext the first would show next go to second and the last would show done and on press close the softkeyboard.

Comment: android:imeOptions="actionNone"

Comment: He actually has to code that functionality in to make it work- the keyboard can't force it to auto-skip to the next field.  It can only tell the app someone hit the "done" or "prev" action button.  So if he isn't coding in the transitions, its useless anyway

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried what you said inmy app and couldnot see the behaviour that you mentioned. The first edittext showed next and clicking it took to the next edittext and at last done was shown. Its android AOSP keyboard. p.s. I didnot write any code to manipulate the keyboard

Comment: Perhaps they added a new feature to the AOSP keyboard.  But its not behavior you can depend on across keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

This is based off the imeOptions for the textfield set in the xml.  Remove the actionDone flag there and it will go away.  Keep only the flags you want there.

Comment: When I used "actionNone", and enter option showed instead. I also tried many other options and none of them is enabling the smiley face only.

Comment: please note that I also tried it with android:singleLine="true" with the same result

Comment: You can't force it to show a smiley.  You can only hint what to do.  Using none will tell it not to use an explicit action.  But not all keyboards will put up a smiley with textShortMessage.  You can't depend on that.